# Eclipse problem with building application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have project in Spring framework from official Spring Github. I imported it into Eclipse IDE, and perform maven build and install - everything was ok, but when I performed project -> build I got errors associated with wrong, undefined constructor, undefined methods, and not applicable type for arguments. 
It is for example:

```
public @PostConstruct void init() {
customers.save(new Customer("Dave", "Matthews", Gender.MALE, //
        new Address("4711 Some Place", "54321", "Charlottesville", "VA")));
 }
```

And following errors for this snippet of code:

`The constructor Address(String, String, String, String) is undefined   Application.java`

`The constructor Customer(String, String, Customer.Gender, Address) is undefined Application.java`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Your project has been imported as maven project?

Comment: Yes, I also deleted this project, and imported it, updated maven project several times.

Comment: Where are `Address` and `Customer` defined? In a JAR (dependency), will they be generated or defined in other language than Java (e.g. Scala), for example?

Comment: It is exactly this project: [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/headers). `Address` and `Customer` are Classes.

Answer (score 0):

What we recommend actually to do when working on `Maven` project  is to build the project externally using the latest `Maven` version (simply, `mvn clean install`) And then, import it to an IDE e.g. `Intellij` or `Eclipse` ( or `STS` since you are using `Spring`).

If the project has been built externally with no issues, then don’t worry if it still complain at IDE level. Maybe a **Project -> clean** or **Maven -> update** solves all errors that you are having.

You have to avoid using IDE embedded `Maven` plugin especially for multi-modules projects (Relying on an external build will keep in shelter from such issues).

Hope that helps.

Comment: But I can build this project successful in Eclipse IDE when i put clean and install as goals in run configuration, and then run it. Cleaning the project, then updating maven didn't solve the problem. Again after Project -> Build I got 5 errors.

Comment: Did you activate the option  project -> build automatically ?

Comment: I tried with activated this option, and building it manually. Same results.

Comment: Intellij Idea IDE dont have problem with this project, but i must build and run it with Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Which confirms that you have an environmental problem that can be dealt with by troubleshooting  Unfortunately, the detail you provided doesn't seem to let SO community help you. Add some details like screenshots of what you got on you eclipse.

Comment: It is very likely problem with lack of Lombok plugin in environment. Intellij Idea underline the lines where object of class is created.